# Duplicate mails sent from PhpMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have created a code, where mails are sent to different people with different bodies, but only if some conditions are satisfied. My code is as follows :

```
set_time_limit(300);
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "*********";
$mail->SetFrom('*********');
$mail->Subject = "System Change";
$add = array("a", "b");
foreach ($add as $address) {
    $mail->clearAttachments();
    $mail->clearAllRecipients();

    if ($Credit == 'N' && $CMU == 'N') {
        if ($Ops_Approval == 'Approved' && $Risk_Approval == 'Approved' && $Finance_Approval == 'Approved') {
            if ($SeniorManagement == 'Y') {
                if ($address == "a") {
                    $mail->AddAddress('********');
                    $mail->MsgHTML("Mail1");
                    $mail->send();
                    if ($mail->Send()) {
                        echo "Mail 1";
                    } else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";
                    exit;
                }
                if ($address == "b") {
                    $mail->AddAddress('****');
                    $mail->MsgHTML("Mail2");
                    $mail->send();
                    if ($mail->Send()) {
                        echo "Mail 2";
                    } else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What is working** - Mails are being sent.
**What is not working** - Both the mails have the same body i.e Mail1 .
I have tried creating different if loops, yet get the same result. Appreciate any suggestions :)

Comment: remove exit; and try

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: If I remove exit, it throws an error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't think 2 mails are sent because you have written exit on if and not on else part.
Try this:-

```
if ( $address == "a" ) {
    $mail->AddAddress('********');
    $mail->MsgHTML("Mail1");
    //$mail->send();
    if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mail 1";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";
        exit;
    }
}
if ( $address == "b" ) {
    $mail->AddAddress('****');
    $mail->MsgHTML("Mail2");
    //$mail->send(); 
    if($mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mail 2";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! tried this but yet sending 2 mails with the same body.

Comment: can you please comment your $mail->send(); before if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Send()` twice by using it again in your if. You can remove the line above `if($mail->send()){`. Also don't forget to put the code after the else inside brackets, otherwise it won't execute the exit.

Comment: You don't need to create multiple instances. You can re-use the same one and just change whichever properties are different, and probably call `clearAddresses` between the two. This is shown in the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.